# Exposing serialization functions in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, serialization

What is the preferred way to expose binary serialization functions in Python?

I sometimes use or write parsers for binary serialization and I encountered several ways to expose serialization/deserialization functions:

- dump(s) and load(s) as in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module
- using [object.__bytes__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bytes__)
- using *serialize()* and *deserialize()* functions

Here is a prototype of a Message object with the above-mentionned functions:

```
class Message(object):

    @staticmethod
    def dumps(obj):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def loads(bytes_object):
        pass

    def __bytes__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_bytes(cls, bytes_object):
        pass

    def serialize(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, bytes_object):
        pass
```

Is there a preferred technique? If not, which one is more common?

Comment: downvoted as i can't see how this question can be made objective

Comment: I don't think there is a commonly 'preferred' example. All 3 options you've mentioned are reasonable.